# NodeJS :: What or which version to use as of October 2018

Tags: node.js

I am very new to Node. and starting to learn it. 
Which version should I follow? I purchased a course in Udemy, but it is all taught in 4.6.0.. at this time today, the LTS is Node.js 8.12.0 .

I am confused about the versions. Are there big differences between these versions? Is it worth learning a NodeJS 4.0 course now at this time ( that is 30th Sep 2018 )

Comment: Learn the course as it is. At the time when you will build something you will easily adapt to the higher versions.

Comment: Yes, there are difference between in each version and major difference between 4 to 10(In 4, you will be using traditional JavaScript while in 8 you will be using modern JavaScript or lates version of JavaScript/ECMAScript), and off-course you can use 4 for learning after that you can start with 10, Even I would like to recommend you to continue with 10 during course as well

Comment: There's nothing wrong with learning how things are done in Node 4. It's still JS, and things are done similarly. Promises and async..await are heavily used in later versions and change things a lot, in a good way. There are almost no compatibility problems, there's no reason to not start with Node 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know the current LTS (as of Sept 2018) is 8.12 and that is what is "recommended for most users" as it says right on the node.js download site. But version 10 is scheduled to become LTS in Oct 2018 so it is almost done at this point.

The even numbered versions are the major versions of node.js.  The odd numbered versions are the more experimental versions.  Only the even numbered versions go LTS and get any sort of longer term support so you should likely pick between 8 and 10.

You can see the Javascript language feature differences between 8 and 10 here: https://node.green/

For practice and learning, I don't see any reason not to pick version 10.  It's already plenty stable and you may as well start with the latest stable version.

Here are a couple of articles that outline what's new in version 10.

[Node v10 is Here - Feature Breakdown!](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-10-lts-feature-breakdown/)

[What's new in Node version 10](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/whats-new-in-node-10-ad360ae55ee4)

In a nutshell, the new features in version 10 are:

- Stable HTTP/2
- Promisified fs module
- Finalized N-API for native code add-ons
- Newest V8 Javascript engine (see http://node.green for language feature differences)

Node version 8 or 10 will have a lot of new stuff in them compared to version 4.  The biggest will be support for the newer language features in ES6, ES7 and ES8.  There are very few "breaking" changes as you advance node.js versions so it's likely you could use your course material with either version 8 or 10.